# Rollup import CSS as constructible CSSStyleSheet

Tags: vite, rollup

I'm switching my project from webpack to vite. Before I imported css as the new constructible stylesheets CSSStyleSheet(). This allows passing it directly to a web components adopted stylesheet:

```
import styles from './styles.css';

class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [styles];
   }
}
```

In webpack, you can configure the css-loader to export to constructible style sheets:

```
{
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              exportType: 'css-style-sheet',
              modules: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

How can I do this in rollup without having to change my code?

Comment: Looking to do the exact same thing using Lit and Vite.

Comment: I found and am using https://github.com/lucaelin/rollup-plugin-cssimport for now.

That said, once vite supports assert imports I will switch to using that syntax.